# swapping values

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I was wondering if there is an easy/clean way of swapping values as follows, perhaps using a single regex/substitution?

If $a ends with "x", substitute it with "y". And similarly if $a ends with "y", swap it with "x":

```
$a = "test_x";

if ($a =~ /x$/) {
  $a =~ s/x$/y/;
} else {
  $a =~ s/y$/x/;
}
```

I can only think of something like this:

```
$a = $a =~ /x$/ ? s/x$/y/ : s/y$/x/;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is simply:

```
$a =~ s/x$/y/ or $a =~ s/y$/x/;
```

It's almost always redundant to do a match to see if you should do a substitution.

Another way:

```
substr($a,-1) =~ y/xy/yx/;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can squeeze it in a line like you show, perhaps a bit nicer with `/r` (with v5.14+).

Or you can prepare a hash. This also relieves the code from hard-coding particular characters.

```
my %swap = (x => 'y', y => 'x', a => 'b', b => 'a');  # expand as needed

my @test = map { 'test_' . $_ } qw(x y a b Z);

for my $string (@test)
{
    $string =~ s| (.)$ | $swap{$1} // $1 |ex;

    say $string;
}
```

The `//` (defined-or) is there to handle the case where the last character isn't in the hash, in which case `$swap{$1}` returns `undef`.  Thanks to [user52889](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4399474/user52889) for the comment.

Comment: `s/(.)$/$swap{$1}/e`: You probably also want to handle the case where the final character is neither `x` nor `y`.

Answer (score 3):

To swap individual characters, you can use `tr///`.

Not sure what your criteria for cleanliness or ease, but you could even do this inside the right hand side of the substitution:

```
$xy = "test_x" =~ s`([xy])$`$1=~tr/xy/yx/r`re; # $xy is "test_y"
```

Comment: Or use this optimized version: `$a =~ s/.$/$&=~y,xy,yx,r/e;`.  But only do this if you hate the people who will have to read your code!

Comment: Optimised for what? `$&` has performance penalties on some perls.

Comment: Optimized for infuriating the people who have to read the code, obviously.